# Eight members of a family

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> There are 8 members in a family. Four of them have positive attitudes while the other four have negative attitudes.

---

> Among the group of four who have ***positive attitudes***, the third member is the child of the first and second members while the fourth member is not.

---

> Among the group of four who have ***negative attitudes***, the third member is the child of the first and second members while the fourth member is not.

---

> The third member in the group of ***positive attitudes*** motivates himself and receives motivation from other 7 members of the family too.

---

> The fourth member in the group of ***negative attitudes*** provides demotivation to other 7 members of the family and demotivates himself as well.

---

***Who are these people?***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think they are

> Blood groups

namely

> A, B, AB and O, with respective -/+ Rh factors

Resolved statements:

> (1/2) AB has A & B antigens, while O has none
>  (3) AB+ receives from all and only gives to AB+
>  (4) O- gives to all, receives only from O-
>  [image]